# How to identify what templates are being loaded in a block-based theme

Tags: block-editor

How can I identify which template and template-parts in a [block-based theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/block-theme-overview/) (These are the very new full-site-editing themes that use all blocks) are being loaded on the front-end when an user is viewing a page?

For example: I'm looking at the Q FSE theme, and I don't know what template is being used to return the search results when I'm viewing it from the front-end.

For 'classic' php-based themes, there are several ways of identifying the templates. For example, you could call `get_included_files` as done in plugins like [show-current-template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/) or use other plugins like [what-the-file](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) and query-monitor.

(An answer to this question would be applicable to all block-based themes; not exclusively to a theme).

Comment: looks like it may be gutenberg_resolve_template , located in lib/template-loader.php